# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

При сборке проекта выдает ошибку:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Где вообще может быть проблема?

Comment: перед этим должен идти лог самого java.exe, содержащий ошибки. посмотрите выше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, оказывается, дело было к регистре названия одной папки.

Comment: @Dumpling, чрез пару дней вы сможете сами отметить сей ответ как правильный.